# Пытаюсь нарисовать черный квадрат на экране

Tags: winapi, c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void main(){
    cout << "Hi!" << endl;

    void* ppix=malloc(32*100*100);
    HBITMAP hbmp=CreateBitmap(100,100,1,24,ppix);

    HDC hmem=CreateCompatibleDC(0);

    SelectObject(hmem, hbmp);

    do 
    {
    BitBlt(0,0,100,100,0,hmem,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    } while (true) ;

    system("pause");
}
```

Но программа зацикливается и ничего не происходит. что не так?

Comment: @ололо, есть отличная книга "Программирование для Windows 95" Чарльза Петцольда. Там есть нужная вам информация. Сам ей пользовался, когда делал подобные вещи.

Comment: Цикл `do {} while (true)` зацикливает программу. Наверное этот цикл не нужен вообще.

Comment: @ildar я пытаюсь рисовать вне окна, о чём говорит (по крайней мере я надеюсь, что говорит) эта строчка - CreateCompatibleDC(0), а точнее 0 - это DC раб. стола.

Comment: @ололо, ЕМНИП сначала нужно получить графический контекст рабочего стола функцией GetDC(), потом уже в него делать BitBlt(), а потом не забыть сделать ReleaseDC(). Если нужен цикл, то делайте все эти операции в теле цикла, и добавьте в цикл хотя бы Sleep(10), чтобы слегка освободить ресурсы.